# How to modify margin spaces for Visio drawing when using 'Auto fit to Drawing'?

Tags: microsoft-visio-2010

I use 'Fit to Drawing' in Visio a lot.

The resized page width fit my drawing objects neatly though putting some extra page margin spaces that I don't want to have.

How can I remove them?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Similar question asked here

https://superuser.com/a/805495/34893

In brief

1. Add `Developer` tab
2. Open `Show ShapeSheet` for `Page`
3. In `Print Properties` Set 0 values for `PageXXXMargin` where XXX to be Left, Right, Top, Bottom

[image]

[image]