# How can actually fit the page size to the drawing in Microsoft Visio 2013?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-visio-2013

I want to fit the page size to the drawing in Microsoft Visio 2013.

When I do `design → Page setup → size → fit to drawing`, they are still some margins:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

There doesn't seem to be any way to change the margin in the page setup either:

[image]

How can actually fit the page size to the drawing? My goal is to export the figure as a PDF with all the surrounding white spaces cropped out.

I use Microsoft Visio 2013 Professional on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: I love the way you create the .gif image which has motion for accessing the menu ^^ !

Comment: @NamGVU Yeah it can take a while to find menu items with their names only :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To remove all margins:

1. On the File tab, click Options, and then in the navigation pane, click Customize Ribbon.

[image]

2. In the Main Tabs pane, click to select the Developer check box, and then click OK.

[image]

3. On the Developer tab, click Show ShapeSheet, and then click Page.

[image]

4. In the Print Properties section of the ShapeSheet, set the following values to 0: PageLeftMargin; 
   PageRightMargin; PageTopMargin; PageBottomMargin

   Otherwise, just set 0 to PageLeftMargin, and value `PageLeftMargin` for the rest i.e. PageRightMargin; PageTopMargin; PageBottomMargin

[image]

5. Use the Fit to Drawing command again. The page now resizes to fit the same dimensions of the drawing, and there is no margin.

Demo: http://youtu.be/3zmVUyg0tMI

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I fully understand what you're trying to do, but the following may be helpful.

1. If you want to set or change margins, on the Page Setup window that you illustrate, click on the "Setup" button next to "Portrait" and "Landscape".  This opens another window that allows you to set margins amongst other things.
2. If you print to a printer (or a PDF creator installed as a printer), the output page size will be the Printer Page size.  However, if you use the Visio 2013 "Save As" option to save as PDF, the output page size will follow the Drawing Page size.  In the example you illustrate, these page  sizes are different, and so these two ways of creating a PDF will give you different page sizes.  This may give you enough control to get what you want.

Comment: This approach worked for me on MS Visio with O365/M365 Plan 2 too.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to change print margins is from the main screen:-
“Developer” tab at the top - “Show Shape Sheet” - “Page”.
Scroll down to ‘Print Properties’. PageLeftMargin = 0.00 mm, then PageTopMargin, etc all = 0.00 mm

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.