# When exporting the selection as PDF in Microsoft Visio, how can I remove the margins?

Tags: microsoft-visio

I want to export the selection in Microsoft Visio.

To do so, when exporting as PDF, I select `Selection`:

[image]

After the export, the PDF  has tons of white margin:

[image]

When exporting the selection as PDF  in Microsoft Visio, how can I remove the margins?

I am aware of [How can actually fit the page size to the drawing in Microsoft Visio 2013?](https://superuser.com/q/805494/116475) but here I don't export the entire drawing, only a few selected items. I'd prefer not to have to copy paste them in a new Microsoft Visio document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your page setup is not properly. Please try the following steps in Visio:

Click **File** > **Print** > **Page Setup**. Under **Print Setup** tab, set the **Printer paper**, under **Page Size** tab, set the set the drawing Page size. Then make the **Pinter Paper** to fit with the **Drawing Page**.

[image]

After finishing the setting, select **Microsoft Print to PDF** as printer, click Print to export to PDF.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't want to have to specify the page size manually: upon export I would like that of the page size fit the selected drawing.